# Inserting an array item and increment a version number ( at one go)

Tags: mongodb

We have a business use case where we open a change stream on a collection and listen to all the updates that are sent over it.

The changes that we receive are then pushed into another mongo DB here we need our data to be stored in this specific format.

First Insert into the destination DB"

```
{
    "_id"   : :"1"
    "name"  : "XXX",
    "value" " "YYY" 
}
delta[]
```

// no updates since this is a first insert

First update to the same id

```
{
    "_id"   : :"1"
    "name"  : "XXX",
    "value" " "YYY" 
}
delta
{
   [ "name","AAA", version : 1 ]
```

// change stream listens to change in name
    }

Second update to the same id.

```
{
    "_id"   : :"1"
    "name"  : "XXX",
    "value" " "YYY" 
}
delta
{
   [ "name","AAA", version : 1 ],[ "value","MMM", version : 2 ] //Second 
}
```

I have been able to achieve the same by using the version field at the top of the document pulling it and adding plus one to it using the $inc operator and then inserting the value into the array index but I would like to achieve the increment in version when ever a new index is added to an array.

Thanks,

Comment: it looks like version is array index + 1, if array elements are inserts only, then it is redundant to store version

Comment: Thanks for reverting back, but if this is the case I would have problems while fetching records is there a way where I can use the index of operator on an mongo array using Java  ? For example if I had the version number pulling them would have been easy with out them I would need a way to use the array index as a version and pull it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out using a sequence easy when you have a record set that is small in size but for my case where the records are a million a day this would not work since for computing the version number for an ID I would have to do a dB hit and this will not scale.